# Is this postgres function cost efficient or still have to clean

Tags: function, postgresql, performance, nested-loops

There are two tables in postgres db.
english_all and english_glob

First table contains words like  international,confidential,booting,cooler ...etc

I have written the function to get the words from english_all then perform for loop for each word to get word list which are not inserted in anglish_glob table. Word list is like

```
I
In
Int
Inte
Inter
..
b
bo
boo
boot
..
c
co
coo
cool
etc..
```

for some reason zwnj(zero-width non-joiner) is added during insertion to english_all table.
But in function I am removing that character with regexp_replace.

Postgres function for_loop_test is taking two parameter min and max based on that I am selecting words from english_all table.

function code is like

```
DECLARE
inMinLength ALIAS FOR $1;
inMaxLength ALIAS FOR $2;
mviews RECORD;
outenglishListRow english_word_list;--custom data type eng_id,english_text
BEGIN
FOR mviews IN SELECT id,english_all_text FROM english_all where wlength between inMinLength and inMaxLength 
ORDER BY english_all_text limit 30 LOOP

FOR i IN 1..char_length(regexp_replace(mviews.english_all_text,'(‌)$','')) LOOP
    FOR outenglishListRow IN
        SELECT distinct on (regexp_replace((substring(mviews.english_all_text from 1 for i)),'(‌)$','')) mviews.id,
        regexp_replace((substring(mviews.english_all_text from 1 for i)),'(‌)$','') where 
        regexp_replace((substring(mviews.english_all_text from 1 for i)),'(‌)$','') not 
        in(select english_glob.english_text from english_glob where i=english_glob.wlength)
        order by regexp_replace((substring(mviews.english_all_text from 1 for i)),'(‌)$','')
    LOOP
    RETURN NEXT outenglishListRow;
    END LOOP;


END LOOP;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Once I get the word list I will insert that into another table english_glob.
My question is is there any thing I can add to or remove from function to make it more efficient.

**edit**
Let assume english_all table have words like

- footer,settle,question,overflow,database,kingdom

If inMinLength = 5 and inmaxLength=7
then in the outer loop

- footer,settle,kingdom

will be selected.
For above 3 words inner two loop will apply to get words like

- f,fo,foo,**foot**,foote,**footer**,s,se,**set**,sett,settl
  .... etc.

In the final process words which are bold will be entered into english_glob with another parameter like 1 to denote it is a proper word and stored in the another filed of english_glob table. Remaining word will be stored with another parameter 0 because in the next call words which are saved in database should not be fetched again.

edit2: 
This is a complete code

```
CREATE TABLE english_all
(
id serial NOT NULL,
english_all_text  text NOT NULL,
wlength integer NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT english_all PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT english_all_kan_text_uq_id UNIQUE (english_all_text)
)

CREATE TABLE english_glob
(
id serial NOT NULL,
english_text  text NOT NULL,
is_prop integer default 1,
CONSTRAINT english_glob PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT english_glob_kan_text_uq_id UNIQUE (english_text)
)

insert into english_all(english_all_text,wlength) values ('ant',char_length('ant')),('forget',char_length('forget')),('forgive',char_length('forgive'));
```

on function call with parameter 3 and 6 fallowing rows should fetched

```
a
an
ant
f
fo
for
forg
forge
forget
```

next is insert to another table based on above row

```
insert into english_glob(english_text,is_prop) 
values 
('a',1),('an',1),
('ant',1),('f',0),
('fo',0),('for',1),
('forg',0),('forge',1),
('forget',1),
```

on function call next time with parameter 3 and 7 fallowing rows should fetched.(because f,fo,for,forg are all entered in english_glob table)

```
forgi
forgiv
forgive
```

[Screenshot](http://img153.imageshack.us/i/addword.jpg/)

Comment: When looking at fastest way if you are using looping logic you are not doing the fastest way. Try and re-work it to use straight SQL when at all possible most of the time this is possible and will be the fastest.  Edge cases you may need to use some PL.

Comment: thanks for the code. You are inserting `1` into `is_prop` for the words `a`, `an`, `ant`, `for`, `forge` and `forget`. How does `PostgreSQL` know they are proper English words and marks them with a `1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in a single statement:

```
SELECT  english_all_text, part,
        part IN
        (
        SELECT  english_text
        FROM    english_glob
        ) AS found
FROM    (
        SELECT  *, SUBSTRING(english_all_text, 1, generate_series(1, LENGTH(english_all_text))) AS part
        FROM    english_all
        WHERE   LENGTH(english_all_text) BETWEEN 5 AND 7
        ) q
```

Some sample data to check:

```
WITH    english_all(english_all_text) AS
        (
        SELECT  unnest('{footer,settle,question,overflow,database,kingdom}'::text[])
        ),
        english_glob(english_text) AS
        (
        SELECT  unnest('{foot,footer,set}'::text[])
        )
SELECT  english_all_text, part,
        part IN
        (
        SELECT  english_text
        FROM    english_glob
        ) AS found
FROM    (
        SELECT  *, SUBSTRING(english_all_text, 1, generate_series(1, LENGTH(english_all_text))) AS part
        FROM    english_all
        WHERE   LENGTH(english_all_text) BETWEEN 5 AND 7
        ) q
```

**Update:**

If you just need to return the words whose parts are not already in the list, use this:

```
SELECT  part
FROM    (
        SELECT  *, SUBSTRING(english_all_text, 1, generate_series(1, LENGTH(english_all_text))) AS part
        FROM    english_all
        WHERE   LENGTH(english_all_text) BETWEEN 5 AND 7
        ) q
WHERE   part NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  english_text
        FROM    english_glob
        )
```

Comment: @Quassnoi not worked at all. The query is simply returning all the rows  from english_all table.Fucntion parameter inMinLength and inMaxLength is also not included in your query itself.

Comment: @kiranking: could you please post some sample data from both tables and the expected output?

Comment: @Quassnoi please check edited question. There is no problem in data fetching but my concern is on the nested for loop. Is it efficient or I still have to tune it.

Comment: @kiranking: please see the query update. Could you please post the resultset you're after, not the verbal description: verbal description may be confusing.

Comment: @Quassnoi I edited the post with more detailed with required result set.

Comment: @Quassnoi. The marks are passed through the page which has two separate buttons manually (see the screenshot link).Once the words are processed ie marked as proper english or not that word should not be fetched again. –